# suggestion Need to handle these kind of issue using javascript code

Tags: javascript, java, html, performance

**Below jsp code:**

```
 <form name="ABC" action="${abc.URLappli}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name ="accountUrl" value="${ABCBean.ACCAccountUrl}"/>
```

Consider an abc.jsp page. In this page(abc.jsp) one 'submit' button. When user click on this button. The Post request goes to the server.

if anyone(attack/heaker) press F12 on browser and added below script on hidden parameter(accountUrl)

```
<input type="hidden" name ="accountUrl" value="javascript:alert(document.cookie)"/>
or 
<input type="hidden" name ="accountUrl" value="<script>alert('Click Here);</script>'"/>
or
<input type="hidden" name ="accountUrl" value="https://www.google.com"/>
```

How can prevent this vulnerable issue using Javascript or java.

Comment: `if anyone(attack/heaker) press F12 on browser and added below script on hidden parameter(accountUrl)` doesn't matter, I can as easily send you a malicious request using curl or Postman or whatever. You need to validate the data on the server. You can't trust anything you get from the client.

Comment: Any Idea on the handle this on the service side  "<input type="hidden" name ="accountUrl" value="javascript:alert(document.cookie)"/>
"

Comment: means what condition I have to put to check

Comment: Can Anyone help, I want check this condition on the server-side. if this kind of script element coming through UI through(attacker/heaker). So what would be best condition to handle this?